# Arreglos dinámicos en metodos(JAVA)

Tags: java

**No logro hacer un metodo set para el arreglo y por ende desconozco como hacer los metodos add ni erase, anexo lo siguiente para meterlos en contexto**:

Clase Doctor: clase derivada de la clase Persona.

patientSet: arreglo dinámico que guarda los números de seguridad social de los
pacientes que están asignados al médico.

o Métodos

Constructores.

Métodos set/get necesarios.

addPatientID: método que añade un paciente (mediante su número de seguro social)
al conjunto de pacientes que el médico atiende. No hay límite respecto al número de
pacientes que un médico puede atender. Si en algún momento el arreglo está lleno,
se debe redimensionar para poder incluir al nuevo paciente.

erasePatientID: libera al paciente cuyo número de seguridad social se proporciona en su lista de argumentos.

```
 public class Doctor extends Person { 

protected String id ; 
protected String deparment; 
protected String license; 
protected ArrayList<Integer> patientSet = new ArrayList(); 

public Doctor(String firstName, String lastName, Integer age, String address, String telephone, String e_mail,String id, String deparment, String license, Integer patientSet){
    super(firstName, lastName, age, address, telephone, e_mail);  
    this.setId(id); 
    this.setDeparment(deparment); 
    this.setLicense(license);

} 

public void setId(String id){this.id = id; }  
public void setDeparment(String deparment){this.deparment = deparment; } 
public void setLicense(String license){this.license = license; } 
public void setPatienset (Integer patienSet){this.patientSet.add(patientSet);} 
public String getId(){ return this.id;} 
public String getDeparment(){return this.deparment;} 
public String getLicense(){return this.license;}  
public void addPatientId(){} 
public void erasePatientId(){}
public String toString(){ 
return("ID: "+ this.id + "DEPARMENT: " + this.deparment + "LICENSE: "+  this.license + "NUMERO de SC DEL PACIENTE: ");}
```

Answer (score 1):

No se si esto sera un ejercicio o quizas este entendiendo mal pero usted dice:

> se debe redimensionar para poder incluir al nuevo paciente.

*patientSet: arreglo dinámico que guarda los números de seguridad social de los pacientes que están asignados al médico.*

usted usa `ArrayList`:

```
protected ArrayList<Integer> patientSet = new ArrayList();
```

este se redimensiona automaticamente sin que usted tenga que hacerlo explicitamente. Por lo que no se si su "codigo" es del todo correcto y lo que usted busca, y tiene que hacer es una implementacion sobre un array primitivo, el cual se redimencione cuando este lo necesite.

---

Dicho lo anterior usted puede usar el metodo [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) sobre el `ArrayList`, si usted puede usar un `ArrayList`,

podria ser algo asi:

```
public void addPatientId(Integer idPaciente){
   patientSet.add(idPaciente);
}
```

sobre lo de borrar, en base a un `ArrayList` usted puede iterear como quiera sobre el y eliminar el registro, (quizas seria bueno de ser posible usar un map o algo similar), un simple ejemplo:

```
public void erasePatientId(Integer idPaciente){
    Iterator<Integer> it = patientSet.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (it.next().equals(idPaciente)) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

puede ver un simple test [aqui](http://ideone.com/5P3WCr)

---

Si lo que usted busca es crear una implementacion para un array dinamico puede mirar estos link (Ingles):

http://theoryapp.com/dynamic-array-class-in-java/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891395/java-dynamic-arrays#15891960

o podria usar alguna de las interfaces que emplea Java, puede echar un vistazo al codigo que emplea java, y hacerse una idea de como lo hace.

El codigo siguiente es el del link de la pagina `theoryapp`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DynamicArray
{
  // El almacenamiento de los elementos. 
  // La capacidad es la longitud de esta matriz.
  private int[] data;

  // El número de elementos (tamaño lógico).
  // Debe ser menor que la capacidad.
  private int size;


  public DynamicArray()
  {
    data = new int[16];
    size = 0;
  }

  public DynamicArray(int capacity)
  {
    if (capacity < 16)
    capacity = 16;
    data = new int[capacity];
    size = 0;
  }

  // Aumenta la capacidad, si es necesario, para asegurar que
  // Que puede contener al menos el número de elementos
  // Especificado por el argumento de capacidad mínima.
  public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)
  {
    int oldCapacity = data.length;
    if (minCapacity > oldCapacity)
    {
      int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 2);
      if (newCapacity < minCapacity)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
      data = Arrays.copyOf(data, newCapacity);
    }
  }

  // Returns the logical size
  public int size()
  {
    return size;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty()
  {
    return size == 0;
  }

  // Comprueba si el índice especificado está dentro del rango.  
  private void rangeCheck(int index)
  {
    if (index >= size || index < 0)
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: " + 
            index + ", Size: " + size);
  }

  // Returns the element at the specified position.
  public int get(int index)
  {
    rangeCheck(index);
    return data[index];
  }

  // Appends the specified element to the end.
  public boolean add(int element)
  {
    ensureCapacity(size + 1);
    data[size++] = element;
    return true;
  }

  // Elimina todos los elementos.
  public void clear()
  {
    size = 0;
  }

  // Reemplaza el elemento en la posición especificada
  public int set(int index, int element)
  {
    rangeCheck(index);
    int oldValue = data[index];
    data[index] = element;
    return oldValue;
  }

  public int capacity()
  {
    return data.length;
  }
}
```

En esta parte `data = Arrays.copyOf(data, newCapacity);` se hace uso de data [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) para copiar los elementos.

*Copia de la matriz especificada, truncando o rellenando con ceros (si es necesario) para que la copia tenga la longitud especificada.*